# Conditional Compilation - Check Scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, conditional-compilation

In a Swift project before I've been able to perform a simple compiler check to see which scheme is running, then conditionally include code or not. For example:

```
#if MyScheme
    Add code here
#endif
```

But for some reason, in my Objective-C project, this doesn't seem to be working. Should this work the same way? Or does the Swift compiler have some advancements which allow this kind of behaviour?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `#ifdef`

```
//example for debug scheme
#ifdef NDEBUG
   Add code here
#endif
```

**And you can define your preprocessor macros here**

[image]

Hope this helps