# Swift flags not working

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing an app that I wan't to make in a free version with an ad banner and a paid version without an ad banner.

My idea is to use an #if statement with a flag to indicate when to display the ad banner.

What I've done is the following:

Created two targets one for the paid version and one for the free version.
Created a flag for the free version target like this:

[image: Other Swift Flags]

In the `viewDidLoad` method I added the following code:

```
    #if FREE
    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
    self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
    bannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - bannerView.frame.size.height, width: bannerView.frame.size.width, height: bannerView.frame.size.height)
    bannerView.adUnitID = ...
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    #endif
```

When I choose the free version and run the code it won't show the ad banner. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you using the Release scheme? Because it looks like you've only set the flag for Release. By default Xcode will run the app as Debug.

Comment: use  #if DEBUG for your debug conditionals if is not in debug is in release then

Comment: check this [Conditional Compilation - Check Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659435/conditional-compilation-check-scheme/45660466#45660466)

Comment: It was running as Debug, now it works fine and I feel pretty stupid. Thanks! :)

Comment: Why are you using build flags? That means you need two builds - one free one with.... an IAP? So they purchase it - and then what? (Specifically if they purchased it from the free app.) There's been established ways *for years* on how to handle this. (Several tutorials about IAP I might add.) Nobody uses build flags for this purpose. Now, AFTER checking out some IAP tutorials (hint, they most use `UserDefaults`) you may need to understand *why* you will also need to **restore* purchases.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is the first time I'm using Swift and XCode, I will look into some tutorials on IAP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Xcode runs builds in the *Debug* build configuration.

If you would like this to work as is when running from Xcode, then either add the flag to the Debug scheme in "Other Swift Flags" or change your scheme to Release (Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run > Build Configuration -- change to Release — I would recommend changing it back after though, not leaving the Run scheme pointing to Release since that would make debugging more difficult.)

If you are making an app with a free / paid version, you might want to consider looking into in-app purchases as **dfd** mentioned in the comments. It is not inconceivable that a developer would want to use Swift flags like this. However, if you're going to be making a single app in Xcode, but distributing it to the App Store as two separate apps, that could be a bit annoying to handle via flags like this.