# Avoid run part of code when use Unit test

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I want that don't execute part of my code when I run the app for Unit testing, the problem is one my functions is save one object in BD and I want avoid this.

```
api.getUsers(completion:{(objects)
//In this response I save the object in BD
})
```

Comment: define a scheme variable for test and check if that variable is false for execute that code

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659435/conditional-compilation-check-scheme/45660466#45660466

Comment: Why not just use(connect) a brand new database for testing?

Comment: The better the design, the easier it is to test. The feeling that "this is hard to test" is trying to tell you something: the design can be improved. Look for ways to extract persistence into a separate, replaceable class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really want to conditionally execute something at runtime based if you are running unit tests or not. That would be a terrible idea IMHO.

What you probably want in your unit tests is to create a *mock* object of your `api` class and then inject the mocked version into the class you are testing.

Answer (score 0):

Does your operating system has environmental values? In React, I solve this with checking `process.env.NODE_ENV !='test'`

Answer (score -1):

You can set an on-launch argument like `isTest` to `YES` in your scheme properties (section Test).

And, in your function use this :

```
BOOL isTest = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isTest"];
```

Comment: Launch arguments cannot be read from `NSUserDefaults` obviously. In order this to work you would need to read `ProcessInfo.processInfo.launchArguments`. Voting down as the OP probably wants a slightly different approach to this.