# How can I switch Crashlytics report by scheme in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crashlytics

My iOS app uses Crashlytics and several schemes to distinguish between Release build and Development build.

I guess the crash report in Crashlytics includes all reports in Release and Development builds.
Can I switch the Crashlytics report by scheme ?

Comment: I usually create different targets for each scheme mostly to be able to have app versions for production and test. In that way my production and test apps always use different Crashlytics keys among other things, such as bundle IDs, url schemes, etc. as they are set in each target's `Info.plist` file.

Comment: @AuRis Thanks for reply. I understand your way, but I cannot create different targets and bundle IDs in release and development builds. Do you know if we can create multi Crashlytics keys for the same bundle IDs ?

Comment: @ken can you kindly test my answer? I will be waiting for feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this preprocessor macros you can easily identify when your app is in one scheme or another,

```
    #if DEBUG
        debugPrint("Debug")
    #else
        debugPrint("Release")
    #endif
```

you can check this answer for further information about [Conditional Compilation - Check Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659435/conditional-compilation-check-scheme/45660466#45660466)

then you can add custom key with the DEBUG value for the Scheme key by example

```
    #if DEBUG
    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setObjectValue("DEBUG", forKey: "Scheme")
    #else
    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setObjectValue("RELEASE", forKey: "Scheme")
    #endif
```

if you put that code in your Application `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method all your crash reports in DEBUG will have the value "DEBUG" in "Scheme" key

**FullCode**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self,Answers.self])
    #if DEBUG
    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setObjectValue("DEBUG", forKey: "Scheme")
    #else
    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setObjectValue("RELEASE", forKey: "Scheme")
    #endif

    return true
}
```

Then in Fabric page you will be able to see it in the crash report selecting **All Sessions**

[image]

Once there with keys switch button in **Keys** you can see the Scheme as key and the value in this case ***DEBUG***

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! and sorry for my late reply. In my understanding, we don't know which part should include "CLSLogv" because we don't know where the crash issue is occurred. So, thought I understood your method can switch the code by Scheme, I don't understand how to use CLSLogv for the crashes which can be occurred everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your very kind reply!! I have tested your way and I could finally check which scheme build occurs the crash issue!